# Android shopping list calculator (OCR)

Tags: android, ocr, calculator, shopping

Is there an Android app to assemble a price list through OCR?

I want to point the camera at price labels, it should OCR them and add name and price from the label to a list, and add up the total.

I want to compare this to the bill to find any incorrectly priced items.

I found several apps with text and speech input, but typing in everything you buy would be even harder then just summing the amount in my head.

Comment: Instead of OCR, ever thought about barcode scanning? For the latter there are several apps to [Compare Prices](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/shopping_deals#group_296) (disclosure: link to my site with app listings).

Comment: yes, thought. But barcode is just a number - item name and price is not there - the items differ for regions, shops, etc. I don't want name and price from regional database - I want price in this particular shop this particular moment, just to save from being deceived.

Comment: The "regional database" might indeed be the show-stopper here – though "regional" usually means at least country-wide in most cases. OK, was just a thought. I'm not aware of any shopping app working with OCR, never stumbled upon one in my researches – but of course I might have missed it. Good luck then!

Comment: At least if you use a barcode scanner you can get 90% of the item.  Sure tapping and entering 1.99 or 11.99 is slower, but not as slow as entering all the info manually.  At least until someone makes the app you want.